# How to use a calculated expression on left-hand-side of an assignment?

Tags: assignment

Elementary question, I guess: I have a left-hand-side something like this:

```
{Subscript[q0, 1, 1], Subscript[q0, 1, 2], Subscript[q0, 1, 3], 
Subscript[q0, 2, 1], Subscript[q0, 2, 2], Subscript[q0, 2, 3], 
Subscript[q0, 3, 1], Subscript[q0, 3, 2], Subscript[q0, 3, 3], 
Subscript[q0, 4, 1], Subscript[q0, 4, 2], Subscript[q0, 4, 3], 
Subscript[q0, 5, 1], Subscript[q0, 5, 2], Subscript[q0, 5, 3], 
(* etc etc etc *)
Subscript[q0, 41, 1], Subscript[q0, 41, 2], Subscript[q0, 41, 3]} = aList
```

Naturally I generate that subscripted expression using a Table. But how can I put it on the left hand side of an assignment without using copy and paste?

Comment: `aList = Table[....]`? I'm not sure what do you mean. Can you clarify? Maybe make a minimal working example.

Comment: Off-topic, but you should really consider switching to expressions like `q0[i, j]` instead of `Subscript`s, **especially** since you are `Set`ting them to values. `Subscript` is meant for formatting purposes, not calculations.

Comment: corey979, I just mean that I write a Table expression to create the syntax that ultimately appears on the left hand side, to save writing that all out by hand.

Comment: Marius Ladegård Meyer, thanks for the suggestion. Subscripted symbols are accepted as variables by FindMinimum, which I later use. That is why I adopted subscripts, which I have never used before. I doubt FindMinimum would work with the function-style expression you proposed, nor with array notation. Fortunately this is not a situation in which I have to manipulate the variables much. I just have to set them once to random values clustered around a known configuration, then hand them off to FindMinimum to calculate an optimized version of the original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Attributes[Set]

(* {HoldFirst, Protected, SequenceHold} *)
```

Since `Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst` you must `Evaluate` the LHS

```
Evaluate[Table[Subscript[q0, m, n], {m, 5}, {n, 3}] // 
    Flatten] = (Array[a, {5, 3}] // Flatten);
```

Then the assignments are made

```
Subscript[q0, 4, 2]

(* a[4, 2] *)
```

Comment: Thank you. That works.